# UWP classes public properties not accessible

Tags: visual-c++, win-universal-app

I have the following code in a Universal Windows App:

```
using namespace Windows::System::Profile;
AnalyticsVersionInfo^ analyticsVersionInfo = ref new AnalyticsVersionInfo();
LOG("DeviceFamily =%s", convert.to_bytes(analyticsVersionInfo->DeviceFamily->Data()).c_str());
```

For an unknown reason the above code does not compile with the following:

```
error C2248: 'Windows::System::Profile::AnalyticsVersionInfo::AnalyticsVersionInfo': cannot access private member declared in class 'Windows::System::Profile::AnalyticsVersionInfo'
```

Although the property I am trying to access is clearly stated to be public in the documentation as in:

> > https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.analyticsversioninfo.devicefamily.aspx

I am having the same issue with many properties and other objects/classes as well.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that there is no public parameterless constructor in class `AnalyticsVersionInfo`, so you can't call `new AnalyticsVersionInfo()`.

From the [Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn960165) section:

> Use [**VersionInfo**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.analyticsinfo.versioninfo) to get an instance of this class.

Comment: Thank you. Missed that!!

Comment: I have the  same issue though with Windows::ApplicationModel::AppInfo , here i can't find if there is any other object through which i could get an instance of it. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.appinfo.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1